# Error de routecollection

Tags: php, laravel

Me muestra el error de **not found**, no se que tipo de error tengo a nivel de código pero me esta mostrando este error. He creado el controlador con ***register,login,logout, getauthuser.***

También he creado las rutas con `logout`,`user`,`products`, `products{id}`, `login`. No se si es un error por las rutas o a que se debe, agradecería la colaboración

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\RegisterAuthRequest;
use App\User;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public $loginAfterSignUp = true;

    public function register(RegisterAuthRequest $request)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->save();

        if ($this->loginAfterSignUp) {
            return $this->login($request);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $user
        ], 200);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $jwt_token = null;

        if (!$jwt_token = JWTAuth::attempt($input)) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Invalid Email or Password',
            ], 401);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'token' => $jwt_token,
        ]);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'token' => 'required'
        ]);

        try {
            JWTAuth::invalidate($request->token);

            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'User logged out successfully'
            ]);
        } catch (JWTException $exception) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Sorry, the user cannot be logged out'
            ], 500);
        }
    }

    public function getAuthUser(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'token' => 'required'
        ]);

        $user = JWTAuth::authenticate($request->token);

        return response()->json(['user' => $user]);
    }
}
```

También aquí estoy  añadiendo las rutas, porque tengo errores en ella, las rutas entre son `register login`
y en el middleware `auth`,`logout`, `user,products,produtcs{id}` uno es **get** y otro es **put** `produtcsc{id}` para `delete`.

api.php

```
<?php

Route::post('login', 'ApiController@login');
Route::get('register', 'ApiController@register');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth.jwt'], function () {
    Route::get('logout', 'ApiController@logout');

    Route::get('user', 'ApiController@getAuthUser');

    Route::get('products', 'ProductController@index');
    Route::get('products/{id}', 'ProductController@show');
    Route::post('products', 'ProductController@store');
    Route::put('products/{id}', 'ProductController@update');
    Route::delete('products/{id}', 'ProductController@destroy');
});
```

> Display me this error 404 Not Found

Tengo un error 404 que no encuentra y entonces estoy teniendo un error con el collection.

Saludos

Comment: como estas consumiendo la api? si te responde con 404 seguramente no le estés apuntado bien a la ruta

Comment: No, estoy apuntando bien a la ruta.. Miss